# Hosting a Private AppStore (for iOS) on SharePoint Online

Tags: ios, sharepoint-2013, enterprise, ipa

I need to distribute apps for my company from SharePoint online platform.
The problem is that when I put on the SharePoint online platform a link like:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=URL/APP.plist">Install App »</a>
```

The system erase it leaving just an empty "a" tag like:

```
<a>Install App »</a>
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there any other way to do that?

why erase it?

Thank you very much

Comment: you will have to find a way to add a new accepted protocol, but what you want to do is definitely possible, have a look at these: [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joerg_sinemus/2011/07/22/how-sharepoint-server-2010-can-work-together-with-lotus-notes/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780738/add-new-accepted-protocol-to-url-link-validation-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: did you look at the links?

Comment: yes, but not clear for me